# Using where condition inside collection filter method - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections

I have a collection that I want to filter if its property value falls under the current month. For that, I am using whereBetween method inside collection filter method but its not filtering any item and returning the whole collection as it is.

I am using Laravel 5.8

Here is my code

**Carbon date**

```
public $c_som, $c_eom

$this->c_som = Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->startOfMonth();
$this->c_eom = Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->endOfMonth();
```

**Collection**

```
"cm_revenue_data": [
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Dr. Joanne Cruickshank",
            "revenue": 1777,
            "doj": "2019-11-16",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-10-25"
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Mack Green",
            "revenue": 2718,
            "doj": "2019-07-28",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-10-25"
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Mrs. Mireille Beer MD",
            "revenue": 1118,
            "doj": "2019-06-18",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-10-25"
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Phoebe Quigley",
            "revenue": 1655,
            "doj": "2019-10-10",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-11-13"
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Johnpaul Prosacco",
            "revenue": 1312,
            "doj": "2019-07-12",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-10-25"
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Alene Moore DVM",
            "revenue": 2059,
            "doj": "2019-10-11",
            "is_claw_back": 0,
            "claw_back_date": null
        },
        {
            "candidate_full_name": "Vida Fisher",
            "revenue": 1955,
            "doj": "2019-09-07",
            "is_claw_back": 1,
            "claw_back_date": "2019-10-25"
        }
]
```

**Filter Method**

```
$cm_revenue_data = $revenue_data->filter(function ($item) {

            return $item
                ->whereBetween('doj', [$this->c_som, $this->c_eom]);
                ->orWhereBetween('claw_back_date', [$this->c_som, $this->c_eom]);
        });
```

Comment: Is that collection data for the current month (11)? Because it looks like it could be for the last month (10)

Comment: Data inside collection may be of current month or past months. I want all that data from collection whose `doj` or `claw_back_date` month is current month

Comment: I got that. What I was asking was: the collection you posted is for the current month (11) and only "Dr. Joanne Cruickshank" and "Phoebe Quigley" should be in it?

Comment: Yes! only `Dr. Joanne Cruickshank` & `Phoebe Quigley` should be in it

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `whereBetween()` isn't quite right because these properties are `string` and the `som` and `eom` are instances of `Carbon`.

If you want to get from the collection, items where the `doj` or `claw_back_date` is the current month then just compare on that property by first casting the `string` to a `Carbon` instance.

```
        $array = [
            [
                'doj' => '2019-11-16',
                'claw_back_date' => '2019-10-25',
            ],
            [
                'doj' => '2019-10-10',
                'claw_back_date' => '2019-11-13',
            ],
            [
                'doj' => '2019-06-18',
                'claw_back_date' => '2019-10-25',
            ],
        ];


        $now = Carbon::now();

        $collection = collect($array)->filter(function ($item) use ($now) {
            if (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item['doj'])->month === $now->month) {
                return true;
            }

            if (Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item['claw_back_date'])->month === $now->month) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        });
```